# Show that if a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ has at least one accumulation point, then $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists x, y \in E: 0<|x-y|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $a$ is an accumulation point of E and $a \in int(E)$

---

By definition, $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R},  [(x,y)\cap E]\backslash\{a\}\neq\emptyset$

---

Since, x and y exist $\Rightarrow \exists x,y \in \mathbb{R}: 0,|x-y|<\epsilon$ by the above definition

Note: $x, y \in E$ as well

---

When x is in the interior, it's easy enough to figure this one out because you can pick any x or y on either side of $a$ and show that the resulting intersection is nonempty.

---

But how do you do it when x is a boundary point of E?

Suppose $a$ is an accumulation point and $a \in$ bound$(E)$

Again, by definition, $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R},  [(x,y)\cap E]\backslash\{x\}\neq\emptyset$

It is true that here, once again, $0<|x-y|<\epsilon$, but if $ \in $ bound$(E)$ and $x<a<y$, then $y ∉ E$ and I need $y \in E$ by the given problem

Comment: Second line has doesn't depend on $a$. Should it be $$\forall \delta >0, E\cap (a-\delta ,a+\delta )\setminus \{a\}\neq\varnothing  ?$$

Comment: That's another way of writing the same thing. For the purposes of this problem, I am keeping the notation with x and y on either side of some given accumulation point $a$

Comment: No it's not the same thing ! Moreover, $E\cap (x,y)\setminus \{x\}=E\cap (x,y)$ always... and still, what's the connection with $a$ defined in the first line ?

Comment: All accumulation points of a given set E are either interior points of E or boundary points of E. I'm saying I understand how to pick an an arbitrary x and y on either side of an accumulation point if the accumulation point is on the interior. But when the accumulation point is on the boundary, then for $x<a<y$, it follows that $y ∉ E$ and the problem I'm doing states that both x and y must be in E

Comment: Also, I meant to make the second line include $a$. Refresh the page, I fixed it. That's my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter whether $a$ is an interior point or a boundary point.

Recall that $a$ is an  accumulation point of $E$ if every neighbourhood of $a$ contains a point of $E$ other than $a$ itself. In other words, for each $\delta > 0$ there exists $x \in E \setminus \{a\}$ such that $\lvert a - x \rvert < \delta$.

Pick $x \in E \setminus \{a\}$ such that $\lvert a - x \rvert < \epsilon/2$. Since $x \ne a$, we have $\lvert a - x \rvert > 0$. Hence we can pick $y \in E \setminus \{a\}$ such that $\lvert a - y \rvert < \lvert a - x \rvert$. But then
$y \ne x$ and
$$0 < \lvert x - y \rvert < \lvert x - a \rvert + \lvert a - y \rvert < \lvert x - a \rvert + \lvert a - x \rvert = 2 \lvert a - x \rvert < \epsilon .$$

Comment: Thank you. I always forget about the triangle inequality!